# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't recognize partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning

I just did a clean install of Windows 7 on a brand new laptop (Packard Bell EasyNote LE).

I created 3 partitions:

- 150 GB on which I installed Windows 7
- 50 GB for Ubuntu
- 270 GB for file storage

When I installed Windows 7, I rebooted and fired up the Ubuntu 12.10 live CD and I was represented with only 2 choices:

- Install Ubuntu and erase everything
- Something else

So I selected *something else* and it lists the 500GB as free space.